# Hover intent not working, or i'm doing something majorly wrong

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hoverintent

I have been trying to figure out this hoverintent plugin and its stumping me. Here is what i have:

```
    var config = {    
     over: $(this).children('.mo_url').css('display','block'), // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
     timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
     out: $(this).children('.mo_url').css('display','none') // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
};

    $('.tag').hoverIntent( config )
```

Im Trying to get a simple tooltip to display after a user highlight a link for a second or 2, to display the url. Is this what i should be using? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: its ok I figured it out. Might help if I put the function tag in.

Comment: if you have answer for your question you'd better post it here (as an answer) and mark it solved: that way somebody who will have the same problem and who has come to this page via google will see how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! It was the interval I was after. Not the timeout.

```
var config = { 
 over: function(){$(this).children('.mo_url').css('display','block')},
 interval: 1000,  // number = milliseconds delay before function init.
 timeout: 0, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
 out: function(){$(this).children('.mo_url').css('display','none')}    
};
```